# Is there a way to download this documentation as a pdf file(may be generated by gitbook)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, download, google-chrome-extensions

[documentation link](https://practical.li/spacemacs/install-spacemacs/line-numbers.html)

It looks like this:
[image]

It seems to be generated by gitbook. How can I download this as a pdf file? Is there such tools(or add-ons for browsers)? I only know a troublesome approach is to write calibre recipes. But it takes a lot of time, and the output is not good-looking.

Comment: The source is avasilable at [GitHub - practicalli/practicalli.github.io: Main website for Practicalli for broadcasts, books and guides on Clojure, ClojureScript, Emacs, Spacemacs and more. Developed with ClojureScript and reagent, using figwheel.main](https://github.com/practicalli/practicalli.github.io)